# Stop reloading jsp page, using href tag with struts bean tags

Tags: struts, href

I don't want my page to reload in href, i am using

```html
<a href='#' id='<%="indent_no">' onclick="openNewWiond('processReport.do?reqCode=generate&indentNo=<bean:write name="list" property="INDENT_NAME" />')">
    <bean:write name="list" property="INDENT_NAME" />
</a>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, or why you'd write `<%= "indent_no" %>`

Comment: You need to add a minimal MCVE.